# xlsExporter in Yii framework

Tags: php, excel, yii

I am using this library in Yii framework.
(https://github.com/faustow/yiiBasicXls/blob/master/XlsExporter.php)

Do you know how can I modify the name of fields in my excel?

I my database I have this names('id_1','id_name', 'id_date') I want change this fields in my excel file with this names: ('Id','name', 'date');

**Controller:**

```
 public function actioncreateExcel() { 
    $criteria= new CDbCriteria(); 
    $fields = array('id_u', 'id_name', 'id_date'); 
    $models = TblUsers::model()->findAll($criteria);      
    XlsExporter::downloadXls('report', $models, false, true, $fields); 
}
```

**View** 
`echo CHtml::submitButton('createExcel',array('submit'=>'index.php?r=user/CreateExcel'));`

Can I use colours in the first row with titles?

Thank you.

Comment: I exported data from database with XlsExporter.php but I need change the fields name.If in the database is id_1 I want in my excel id

Comment: and where is the code you used to export data?

Comment: I have an action in my controller.

I am using CDbCriteria to find all data from table and export with this library to excel.

Comment: I mean you should post your code here, so people can see what are you trying to do, and maybe someone will know how to help you do it in the way you want

Comment: Ok


In my controller:


`public function actioncreateExcel()
 {
  $criteria= new CDbCriteria();
     $fields = array('id_u', 'id_name', 'id_date'); 
     $models = TblUsers::model()->findAll($criteria);
  XlsExporter::downloadXls('report', $models, false, true, $fields);
 }`


In my View


`echo CHtml::submitButton('create Excel', array('submit'=>'index.php?r=user/CreateExcel'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this: (not sure if it will work, don't have possibility to test that now)

```
public function actioncreateExcel() { 
    $criteria= new CDbCriteria(); 
    $fields = array('id_u', 'id_name', 'id_date');
    $headerFields = array('Id', 'name', 'date');
    $criteria->select = $fields;
    $models = TblUsers::model()->findAll($criteria);      
    XlsExporter::downloadXls('report', $models, false, true, $headerFields); 
}
```

**Update:**

Checked `XlsExporter.php` source code, for header it uses `getAttributeLabel()` of field, so set attribute labels in model as you want them to be displayed.

Comment: It's not working. Id is not  defined,

Maybe I need to create a new function in my model with specific fields in  my search I want to display. 

Thanks !!

Comment: Yeah code before update probably won't work (with `$headerFields`). Just try to set  `attributeLabels()` in model like 'id_u' => 'Id' etc. I think that should work

Answer (score 0):

Perfect,
I need to set my attributeLabels() in my model.

This solution is working.

Thank you.

Comment: no problem ) but you shouldn't have posted this comment as an answer